# SQL statement with multiple Or and And conditions

Tags: sql

i have a problem i cant find the solution right now.

here is an example sql statement of my kind:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ((id IS '2' AND name IS 'foo' ) OR 
   (is IS '3' AND name IS 'bar' ) OR 
   (id IS '4' AND name IS 'foobar'))
```

for any reason it only returns one row but it should return all 3 rows.

EDIT:

I found my error and it was nothing but stupidness of mine.
sorry for your inconvenience.....

in my real statement all ORd clauses where equal and i couldnt see the tree for the forest..

Comment: `(is IS '3' AND name IS 'bar' )` you have a typo here you have `is IS` instead of `id`..

Comment: One hopes for there not to be a column called is...

Comment: thx. fixed the typo. But that was not my problem :)

Comment: What's the data you're selecting from?

Comment: all columns contain simple texts in sqlite

Comment: Can we see the three rows it should be returning?

Comment: @user1250639 Show your data. Otherwise it's impossible to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Can you use = instead of "IS"

Comment: it should return:

'2', 'foo' and '2', 'bar' and '3', 'foobar'  and for each row an arbitrary number of columns

Comment: You said it was supposed to return three rows

Comment: When I test it (using `=` instead of `is` because of the SQL dialect), I get all rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33959/3

Comment: `id IS '2'` is invalid SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense with any SQL server I've ever used. The IS operator only works against null - IS will always be false against non-null columns.

Comment: sqlite and it worked as expected (until now) with = i have no different result

Comment: @user1250639. as stated multiple times, your problem is most likely with data. try one row at a time to see if you can get the rows you want. it is probably weird characters or spaces in your data. And i would change from IS to = too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd almost say the problem is in your data, but you're not giving us enough info.  Check your table and make sure you're querying appropriately.   Based on your statement, your query should work (with corrected fixes).  Look at the [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e1bb3/3) linke here.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: With an example to show/confirm his query.  What's the problem, really? In a case like this, is formalities more important than putting the op on the right path?

Comment: Comments are for clarifying information and posting suggestions. Answers are supposed to provide definitive information. They're two different things, which is why they both exist at the same time. :-) It's not a question about formalities; it's an issue with maintaining quality so that the information is helpful to future readers as well, not just this poster with an immediate need. "You need to provide more info" isn't an answer. The [help] has more information about what answers should contain in [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would be more than happy to discuss offline with you, but rest assured, "provide more info" was not my focal point.  My goal was to provide the OP with a live version of his query and confirm that it works (no different than your post).  FWIW, there's no intent to pick an argument with you.  ;-)

Comment: Not wanting to argue either; just providing what's intended to be constructive feedback. The difference between my answer and yours is that yours relies primarily on content not contained here, making it unusable if the off-site location is unavailable for some reason. External content is also not searchable here. So IMO your answer is "You need to provide more info. It works for me somewhere else". As I said, the focus here at SO is not to solve the poster's immediate problem, but to provide a repo of info useful to others in the future as well. :-)

Comment: Now you make a very valid point about the off site references and will keep that in mind for future postings.  Consider us on the same page now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use standard SQL syntax wherever possible.

```
SELECT * FROM table

ID    NAME
==    ====
1     boo
2     foo
3     bar
4     foobar

SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table
WHERE 
  (id = '2' AND name = 'foo' ) OR 
  (id = '3' AND name = 'bar' ) OR 
  (id = '4' AND name = 'foobar')

ID    NAME
==    ====
2     foo
3     bar
4     foobar
```